# Adding onTouchListener on Button inside fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, ontouchlistener

I am trying to add an onTouchListner on a Button Inside a fragment. This code works fine in main activity but not on the fragment. All I want to do is certain sound file to play as long as button is pressed. Any help would be appreciated.

Code is

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    message1();

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_a, container, false);


}

public  void message1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         ImageButton one1 = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


         one1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int resID =   R.raw.a;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //mp.setLooping(true);

                    if (mp != null) {
                         mp.release();
                      }
                      // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
                      mp = MediaPlayer.create( getActivity(), resID);
                      mp.start();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    mp.stop();

                    break;
                }

                return true;

            }
```

});

Comment: Have you checked after doin debugging? I mean have you got any error or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout has not been inflated when you call `message1()`. So the `findViewById` cannot find your button as it does not exist in view hierarchy.

Try the following:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_a, container, false)
    ImageButton one1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    one1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int resID =   R.raw.a;
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //mp.setLooping(true);

                if (mp != null) {
                     mp.release();
                  }
                  // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
                  mp = MediaPlayer.create( getActivity(), resID);
                  mp.start();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                mp.stop();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return view;


}
```